# Safari extensions: style of selectbox like safari's bookmark folders

Tags: css, safari

I'm developing an extension for Safari 5 at the moment.

In my extension, I use an additional toolbar, with selectboxes in it. Now, it would be great to style these like the folders in the bookmarks toolbar look.

I know that it would be possible to replace my select with a completely styleable ul-list or somethin like that, but maybe there is a simpler solution.
Doesn't apple provide extra tools to imitate their look?

Best regards and thanks for help,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-webkit-appearance: none;` can be used to remove the select control's appearance, from there you can style it like any other HTML element.

http://cmorrell.com/safari-extensions might be a good place to start with trying to emulate the bookmarks bar look.